# What does the "Object Access Level" reference in step three of the Import Wizard?

Tags: data-import-wizard

When using the web-based import wizard no matter which label (really, object, but the UI calls it a label) is selected, the "Object Access Level" look up field is present in `Step 3 - Specify Relationship`s.  What is the Object Access Level look up field referencing? I don't have an object called anything like this.

[image: What's this thing?!]

I suspect this is related somehow to the salesforce sharing model, but I'm not sure entirely how. Really I'm looking to understand what the "Object Access Level" means in this context.

Most other labels from Step 3 - Specify Relationships have more than just the "Object Access Level" look up field. I understand most look up fields and where they reference. Since Object Access Level is present on every label, what does it do. I'm not seeing any documentation on "Object Access Level". Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add more details like what are you trying to do? Which operation like insert upsert etc. Also elaborate your question.

Comment: Looking to understand what the "Object Access Level" means.  Most other labels from Step 3 - Specify Relationships have more than just the "Object Access Level" look up field.  I understand most look up fields and where they reference.  Since Object Access Level is present on every label, what does it do.  I'm not seeing any documentation on "Object Access Level".  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an idea of: Which import wizard you are using. The object you are trying to import. Some sample data. A screenshot.

Comment: Below is a screen shot using jing.  http://screencast.com/t/Zbi1ITQsqnAI